# covariance matrix in multivariate Gaussian distribution (semi-positive or positive definite)

Tags: matrices, covariance

The book that I'm reading states clearly that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ in the following equation is a positive semidefinite and symmetric matrix.

$$
p(x) = det(2\pi\Sigma)^{-1/2} exp\{ -\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)  \}
$$

However, when I use  [mvnpdf()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html) in Matlab, I get an error that the covariance matrix must be a positive definite matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: what matrixc do you enter into matlab exactly?

Comment: @NikosM., the sigma $\Sigma$ along the $x$ and $\mu$. I have checked the Eigen values of the covariance matrix and they are positive.

Comment: yes ok, but what is the matrix exactly, matlab needs some numbers there, no? i suspect the (actual) matrix is wrong or sth

Comment: @NikosM., my question is why in Matlab's documentation the covariance matrix is positive definite whereas in my book is semipositive definite regardless of the actual values?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Matlab being a numeric software will need to **actually compute** the PDF using a numeric algorithm and this makes the case where $\Sigma$ is semi-positive-definite or singular problematic. As stated in Matlab's documentation page:

> ..where $x$ and $\mu$ are 1-by-d vectors and $\Sigma$ is a d-by-d
>   symmetric positive definite matrix. **While it is possible to define
>   the multivariate normal for singular $\Sigma$**, the density cannot be
>   written as above. **Only random vector generation is supported for the
>   singular case**. Note that while most textbooks define the
>   multivariate normal with $x$ and $\mu$ oriented as column vectors, for
>   the purposes of data analysis software, it is more convenient to
>   orient them as row vectors, and Statistics Toolbox™ software uses that
>   orientation.